# How do I secure my Microsoft Bot Framework iframe WebChat url

Tags: authentication, botframework

I would like to use 'https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/QuizHS?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE' to integrate it with Web Application. 
But, I would like to secure the conversation by passing token to it as Secret key is in querystring, so that no one can copy above link directly and use it in any other application as this data contain confidential data.

Comment: If you can make a server call from your web application, you can request a token by issuing a GET request to “https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens” and pass your web chat secret as the Authorization header. Then you can use "t=" in the query string of your webchat URL instead of "s=" and pass the token obtained. See https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/embed-chat-control2/#option-1---keep-your-secret-hidden-exchange-your-secret-for-a-token-and-generate-the-embed for further details.

Comment: Using [link](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/support/embed-chat-control2/), I am able to generate token but again i need to send this token as querystring parameter which is not secure. Can't we hide it from user and still use webchat URL?

Comment: Thanks Raj, I just did that. Along with that, I sent webchat URL with token to my mobile and I opened that link from mobile as well as from my laptop.  it opened in both location and data is shared. That is security problem. I don't want other to use link directly only through specific application.

Comment: @HARDIKSHAH If you are using t=[token], then only your web app will be allowed to embed the webchat control with the token.  Try embedding the webchat control on another site using that token. It will not work.

Comment: I send below link to another person through email. https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/QuizHS?t=with_token ... that person click on the link and able to see the chat. I think, token expire in 30 mins so if somebody see the link before expire they will able to the data. Here, both me and that person able to see same chat and anyone is able to respond to chat.

Comment: Can't we send token in header during the request?

Comment: @Eric Dahlvang, you are right. Ideally you should not be able to use same token to embed on another website. But, here it is happening. Do you think its a bug?

Comment: @HARDIKSHAH I will investigate this further, and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for adding it in enhancement.  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2601

Comment: @HARDIKSHAH, Are you able to overcome this problem? If yes then kindly share the logic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered extensively by Dan Driscoll here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/428

> For purposes of this discussion, we're going to treat secrets and
>   tokens to be the same thing. We can go into detail on those later if
>   you want. I'll refer to them as "secret/token" for now.
>
> To access a conversation, you need the secret/token and a conversation
>   ID. These values are sometimes glued together, and are sometimes in
>   separate variables. Sometimes they're in the URL, and sometimes
>   they're stored in JavaScript in memory. These are similar to a user
>   token, stored in a user's cookie.
>
> In all cases, these values are accessible to a user sitting at their
>   own computer. They can read their own URLs, they can read their own
>   JavaScript variable state, and they can read their own cookies.
>
> If they send any of this information to someone else, that person can
>   impersonate them. If my bank emails me a password reset link, and I
>   share that with someone else, that person can reset my account
>   password and log in to my account.
>
> Our iFrame uses URLs to pass these parameters, as that's an adequate
>   level of security in many cases. (Have you ever visited a website,
>   manually extracted the URL to an iFrame, sent it to someone else, and
>   expected your session to remain private? Probably not.)
>
> If you want additional security, you can skip the iFrame and send your
>   own secret/token inside JS or a cookie. Your JS can extract that and
>   send it to the Web Chat JS object. Once Web Chat has the secret/token,
>   is exclusively uses HTTP Authorization headers to send those values to
>   the Direct Line service.